# Reusing django code auto-reload functionality for custom management commands

Tags: django, django-command-extensions

I love how django server auto-reloads itself on code change, so that no restarting the server is required.

We currently use django custom management commands that may take a very long time to complete.

> Is there any way we can use the
>   auto-reloading feature of the django
>   server for our management command?

For example, if the change of the underlying django codebase is detected, the command reloads itself and resumes execution of the very long (stateless) loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the way [runserver](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py#L69) (specifically the run method) does it with the [django.utils.autoreload](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/autoreload.py) module.  You'll want to copy this pattern with your custom command.

Answer (score 13):

Whatever your management command is doing, abstract that to a single function and call that function using `django.utils.autoreload.main`

```
from django.utils import autoreload

def do_something(*args, **kwargs):
    # management command logic


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout('This command auto reloads. No need to restart...')
        autoreload.main(do_something, args=None, kwargs=None)
```

For django 2.2 or above use

```
        autoreload.run_with_reloader(do_something, args=None, kwargs=None)
```

Comment: `autoreload.main()` is gone now as of https://github.com/django/django/commit/c8720e7696ca41f3262d5369365cc1bd72a216ca#diff-46e69f287173eef41fcbfeba05501954